# Misspecification bias

Tags: econometrics

I'm thinking about the following problem:

Suppose we have the equation that describes the true beta parameter for $y^{*}$

$$z=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}y^{*}+\epsilon$$

But instead, we only can only use $y$ to measure $y^{*}$ as

$y=y^{*}+\gamma$

Then, we estimate the following equation

$z=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}y+\mu$

Making some assumptions ($\beta_{1}>0$, no correlation between $y$ and $\gamma$, between $y$ and $\epsilon$ or between $\epsilon$ and $\gamma$.) I have to prove that $E(y\mu)<0$.).

I tried by rewriting the last equation as :

$z=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}y+\epsilon+\beta_{1}\gamma$

where

$\mu=\epsilon+\beta_{1}\gamma$

knowing that $\hat{\beta}={cov(y,z)}{v(y)}$ I can derive the following expression $\hat{\beta}=\beta_{1}+{cov(\gamma, z)}{v(y)}$, but I'm stuck now and cant think about how to proceed to prove that $y$ and $\mu$ are negatively correlated.

Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note that the question, as you have written it, is a poor way to get you to understand the attenuation bias that arises out of classical measurement error in the independent variable. But before I get into why, let me first answer your question as it is posed. First, to simplify notation, I’m going to assume a model without a constant where $\mathbb{E}[y^*_i] = 0$; this is equivalent to your model as stated. We then have

$$ z_i = \beta_1 y^*_i + \epsilon_i \tag{1} $$ and
$$ z_i = \delta_1y + \mu. $$

We can then compute the following
$$
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{E}[y \mu ] &= \mathbb{E}[y(\beta_1 y^* + \epsilon - \delta_1(y^* + \gamma)] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(y^* + \gamma)((\beta_1 - \delta_1)y^* - \delta_1 \gamma + \epsilon] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(y^* + \gamma)((\beta_1 - \delta_1)y^* - \delta_1 \gamma] \\
&= (\beta_1 - \delta_1)\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[y^*] - \delta_1 \mathbb{V}\text{ar}[\gamma].
\end{align*}
$$

Note that in the third and fourth equalities, we used our orthogonality assumptions. Now, we can *impose* $\delta_1 = \beta_1$ to recover the negative covariance that you needed. This is a little awkward, as there’s no good *a priori* reason to do impose this equality. Instead, it is better to set the above equality to zero (since that’s what the actual estimator would do in sample!) and recover that

$$ \delta_1 = \beta_1 \frac{\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(y^*)}{\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(y^*) + \mathbb{V}\text{ar}(\gamma)} $$

which best highlights the aspect of measurement error basically crowding out the *signal* in $y^*$ with the noise in $\gamma$.